# iMac 2017 5k host, iMac 2017 21 target display mode

Tags: display, imac

I am using my iMac 2017 5k as my main machine and want to use my 21 inch 2017 iMac in target display mode.

When I try <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> I hear a beep and nothing happens. I have also tried doing it at the login screen and also tried <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> but nothing worked. What am I doing wrong? Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of your Macs support target display mode. Below are the Macs that do.

- iMac (27-inch, Late 2009)
- iMac (27-inch, Mid 2010)
- iMac (Mid 2011-Mid 2014)

For more information see [Use your iMac as a display with Target Display Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592).

Comment: What is a good workaround david?

Comment: I do not know of any good workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

I know that I'm three years late, but with MacOS Monterey coming out of beta in a few months, I would like to say that apple re-established such a feature with AirPlay over USB to iMacs 2019 or later. So, not for you personally, but anybody who has a supported mac or iPad (yeah, you can use wireless mode to airplay to your iPad!) can airplay to their device using a USB cable or using wifi (USB cable is faster but still compressed).