# Problems using an iMac as an external monitor

Tags: display, imac

My iMac is not detecting my MacBook. Pressing <kbd>Command</kbd> and <kbd>F2</kbd>, but nothing happens. I am trying to use my iMac as an external display from my MacBook.

Comment: Which iMac & which macBook precisely? How are you connected? It only works on specific models with specific cabling.

Comment: Have a look at **System Requirements** and **If Command-F2 doesn't work** in: [Use your iMac as a display with Target Display Mode](https://support.apple.com/HT204592)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Feel free to edit in some details. We don’t want to keep this open if it’s a duplicate of other questions like https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/313294/imac-2017-5k-host-imac-2017-21-target-display-mode?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried all the [steps recommended by Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592)?

> ## Use Target Display Mode
>
> Follow these steps to start using your iMac as a display:
>
> 1. Make sure that your iMac is turned on, and the other Mac is logged in to a macOS user account.
> 2. Connect the Mini DisplayPort or Thunderbolt cable between the two computers.
> 3. Press Command-F2 on the keyboard of the iMac that you want to use as a display.
>
> After you press Command-F2, your iMac displays the desktop from the connected Mac.
>
> ### If Command-F2 doesn't work
>
> If your iMac doesn't switch to Target Display Mode when you press Command-F2, check these things:
>
> - Make sure that the iMac you're trying to use as a display supports Target Display Mode.
> - Target Display Mode works only when your primary Mac is logged in to a macOS user account. For example, if your first Mac is at the FileVault login screen, pressing Command-F2 on your iMac does not enable Target Display Mode. You must first log in to your Mac (using a regular display, if necessary) before you can use an iMac in Target Display Mode.
> - Make sure that you're pressing Command-F2 on the keyboard that's connected to the iMac you want to use as a display.
> - In Keyboard System Preferences, if the checkbox is enabled for "Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys," the key combination changes to Command-Fn-F2.
> - Make sure that your Mini DisplayPort or Thunderbolt cable is connected to both computers.
> - If you're currently logged in on the iMac you want to use as a display, try logging out to return to the login window. Then press Command-F2 again.
> - Some older Apple keyboards and third-party keyboards might not allow Command-F2 to toggle display modes. If this happens, use the keyboard that came with your iMac to toggle Target Display Mode on and off.
> - If your iMac is currently started up in Windows, it won't enter Target Display Mode. Target Display Mode isn't supported in Boot Camp.